# How to continue on error if the secondary datasource not accessible?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

We have a spring boot application where we configured two Datasource.

1. SQL Server
2. Postgres

We would like to run application even though secondary Datasource not accessible on startup.

So far I tried spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true and spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true configuration but it was not working.

Please find below yaml configuration for primary and secondary datasource. We are using spring boot version 2.6.6.

```
spring:
   datasource:
     primary:
       type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
       url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:58459;database=abcd;encrypt=false
       username: sa
       password: 1234
       liquibase:
          change-log: classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml
       hikari:
          poolName: Hikari
          auto-commit: false
          data-source-properties:
               cachePrepStmts: true
               prepStmtCacheSize: 250
               prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
               useServerPrepStmts: true
     secondary:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abcd
        username: sa
        password: 1234
        driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        physical_naming_strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        liquibase:
          change-log: classpath:config/liquibase/master-postgre.xml
```

Comment: Can you add the spring boot version that you are using?

Comment: updated above question with spring boot version.